# Which of these commands actually installs gcc?

Tags: system-installation, cross-compilation

I'm writing a "custom" Linux system, mainly using [this](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/diy-build-custom-minimal-linux-distribution-source) guide. Great guide! But, my problem is, once I boot into my system, I don't have `gcc`. Now, it's completely possible that I missed a command from the guide - it's happened before. But, I'd like to understand, which of the commands that are in there actually gets me the `gcc` command?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From "Building the Cross Compiler" onwards. You download the packages (gcc etc.), decompress them to get a static GCC, then use that to build the "real" GCC ("Uncompress the GCC tarball, and then uncompress the following packages and move them into the GCC root directory: ")

Comment: Thanks for your response! At which point does the `gcc` bin file go onto my system though? I'm just trying to diagnose why `gcc` isn't available.

Comment: That should happen when you un-tar the gcc...tgz file. *That* gcc is not available from everywhere, just from the directory you uncompress it in, though.

Comment: So, where is my `gcc` in the system-to-be?

Comment: Did you follow that guide, the "Building the Cross Compiler" section? It should be initially in the LJOS tree, then it will install gcc in the default path (/usr/bin/gcc I think).

If you ran the bootstrap build stage ("make all-gcc all-target-libgcc && \
make install-gcc install-target-libgcc") it should have signaled where the installation directories were.

Comment: I did indeed follow the guide - but I wouldn't be surprised if I missed something, lol. But when I `ls /bin | grep gcc`, I get no output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113767/discussion-between-lserni-and-bobbay).

Answer (score 1):

None. This guide doesn't install gcc on the target system. It builds a minimal system that doesn't include a compiler. The compiler that compiles programs for the target system runs on the host system.

The goal of installing a minimal system is typically to set up an embedded device which is not powerful enough to comfortably run a compiler. If you're doing this as a learning exercise to set up a system that is capable of doing development, that guide won't help you much. Follow [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) instead.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your comment - definitely clears things up. I have a problem with LFS, because the community has not proved to be responsive (I've tried LFS first). Just to check though, it's still *possible* to install `gcc` on this, correct? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Bobbay Possible, yes. But if you need to ask, you aren't going to manage. Starting with a minimal busybox-based system is far from the easiest path to building a system where you can do development.

Comment: Well, thanks for your responses - I'll definitely consider them. I was able to get gcc on my target system up in a jiffy, lol. Thanks for the help!